# Passing a supplier to log4j2 along with normal objects doesn't compile

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j 2.4.1, which is supposed to support lambda expressions.

So I'm writing this call which doesn't compile.

```
logger.trace("{}{}", "foo", ()->"bar");
```

Yet, the two following lines work properly:

```
logger.trace("{}{}", "foo", "bar");
logger.trace("{}{}", ()->"foo", ()->"bar");
```

I just don't understand why I can't pass Supplier as an Object here...

What makes it impossible to compile, and what suggestion should I make to the log4j team to fix this?

The compile error is the following:

```
no suitable method found for trace(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,()->"bar")
```

Comment: doesn't compile: with error? cannot find symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant methods available on `Logger` are:

```
...
trace(String, Object...); // all parameters are non-lambda Objects
trace(String, Supplier<?>...); // all parameters are lambda expressions
...
```

This means you can either pass one ore more parameters of any (non-lambda) object, or you can pass one or more lambda expressions as parameters.

To support what you have in mind, the following method would need to be added to the Logger interface:

```
 // support one Object param followed by one or more lambda expressions
 trace(String, Object, Supplier<?>...);
```

However, this would only help with `logger.trace("{}{}", "foo", ()->"bar")`, and not for something like `logger.trace("{}{}{}", "foo", ()->"bar", "xxx")`.

I don't think it is possible to support any random mixture of Object parameters and lambda expression parameters in a generic way.

Comment: "you can either pass one ore more parameters of any (non-lambda) object". Yeah, I figured all that. But why? A `Supplier` is still an `Object` in my book...

Comment: I think Javac is giving lambda expressions special treatment. (The result of calling toString() on a lamda is pretty cryptic...)